# VBA Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: vba

Please help me resolving the error. Error is happening at rs.RecordCount. It looks like out put is not returned to rs. When I tried to check the value in rs.Fields(0).Value, I got "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal".

```
   vJobName = "JOBName"
   StrQuery = ""
   StrQuery = " SET NOCOUNT ON;" + vbCrLf
   StrQuery = StrQuery & "DECLARE @vJobStatus Integer;"
   StrQuery = StrQuery & " EXEC RDW.dbo.Run_SQL_Job '" & vJobName & "' , @vJobStatus OUTPUT;"
   StrQuery = StrQuery & " SELECT @vJobStatus as vJobStatus"
   Set rs = cnn.Execute(StrQuery)
   If (rs.RecordCount <> 0) Then
       vJobStatus = rs.Fields(0).Value
   End If
```

Comment: Have You declared rs object earlier? Dim rs As DAO.Recordset?

Comment: I have declared the recordset

Comment: rs.fields(0).value is not getting any value and throwing error "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal"